# Installing AC-7265 wireless drivers on existing ESXI 6 server

Tags: esxi, wifi-driver

I have an Intel NUC5i5RYH with an embedded Intel AC-7265 dual band wireless card. My issue is that ESXI can only see the ethernet NIC whereas I want it to run on the wireless card.

VMWare uses .vib files to install drivers and the like, but I can only find Windows drivers for this particular card.

Does anyone have any insight into how I might accomplish getting these drivers on an existing ESXI installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That adapter is (currently) [incompatible with ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) - there are no drivers to be had.

[Contact Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/company-overview/contact-us.html) about it, and/or get a known-compatible adapter.

You may also want to check out this article: [How to make your unsupported NIC work with ESXi 5.x or 6.0](http://www.v-front.de/2014/12/how-to-make-your-unsupported-nic-work.html) which states:

> You should also skip to step 7 now if your NIC is a wireless device or
>   connected through a USB port. There is no way to get these working in
>   ESXi...

Step 7:

> Always easy: Go and get a compatible controller!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have my ethernet NIC working fine. Bummer on the wireless end, though!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found way to configure ESXI without wired connection. You need two computers may be laptops, sim wifi adapter or sim wireless router (idk if ad hoc would work too...), ethernet cable + ravpower. IDK about passthrough to ESXI vm.

LAN (panel) / WIFI (WAN) #1 PC Over-lapsed Direct WIFI Access Point

```
    1st PC
    WIFI (replacable by Ethernet)
    192.168.0.29
    255.255.255.0
    192.168.0.1
    DNS
```

Ethernet (LAN panel) connected to PC2

```
    192.168.0.36
```

Description: 192.168.0.35 as 192.168.0.36 to prevent IP conflict. Best to use this settings and second WIFI dongle for access to internet. (see belowi t kinda works like I have descripted)

```
    255.255.255.0
    192.168.0.1
    DNS
```

Desc: DNS should not be not used for better connection

```
    2st PC
    Ethernet (LAN) connected to PC1
    192.168.0.35
    255.255.255.0
    192.168.0.29
    DNS
```

Desc: DNS are optional

LAN (panel) / WIFI (WAN) #2 „PC Sub-Route  WIFIAccess Point”

```
    1st PC
    WIFI (replacable by Ethernet)
    192.168.0.29
    255.255.255.0
    192.168.0.1
    DNS

    Ethernet (LAN panel)
    192.168.0.36
```

Description: 192.168.0.35 as 192.168.0.36 to prevent IP conflict
        255.255.255.0
        192.168.0.29
Desc: may be slower in fetching. This way kinda allow to have both WAN and LAN (at least for me with server-ready router (no over-lapsing DHCP, added MAC adresses, no limited bridge mode, specific adjustment of port channels or VLAN settings, firewall whitelist). 
        DNS
Desc: DNS should not be not used for better connection

```
    2st PC
    Ethernet (LAN)
    192.168.0.35
    255.255.255.0
    192.168.0.29
    DNS
```

Desc: DNS are optional

LAN (panel) / WIFI (WAN) #3 „PC WIFI Access Point 2step” – my preffered one I use along with vm

```
    1st PC
    WIFI (replacable by Ethernet)
    192.168.0.29
    255.255.255.0
    192.168.0.1
    DNS

    Ethernet (LAN panel)
    192.168.0.36
```

Description: 192.168.0.35 as 192.168.0.36 to prevent IP conflict

```
    255.255.255.0
    192.168.0.29
```

Desc: or 192.168.0.1…

```
    DNS
```

Desc: DNS should not be not used for better connection

```
    2st PC
    Ethernet (LAN)
    192.168.0.35
    255.255.255.0
    192.168.0.36
    DNS
```

Desc: DNS are optional

169.254.249.200 mask: 255:255:0:0 (what DHCP shows for PC2) are private ranges IPs.

Not supported on cable/TV modem or PPoE or Per to Per or pci passthrough (bluetooth etc) or ad-hoc (likely, so you would need to insert your SIM inside wifi adapter or better portable router) or access point with DHCP functionality (kinda my case). You need two internet cards or abgn card. Only DSL standard modem.
While Ethernet is on it’s replaces WIFI settings – Case #1.
You can use wireless nic Tp Link tl WN-823N to connect to wifi then.
Without routing  on one card (setting server with WIFI access to internet and IP address for connecting to host) or vm passthrough not possible to do in some cases. It uses LAN of ESXI to access panel from second PC and it makes your wifi card busy so you need second dongle or vm and host not bridged network to connect to WAN (internet). On some server wifi cards it should work independently I think…